# Skimage read always images as float but in my case it is not?

Tags: python, scikit-image

As far as I know, skiamge library reads images in float but for my image, it shows me in **uint8**, could someone please guide me why?
the code is :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import io, color
from skimage.transform import rescale, resize, downscale_local_mean

img = io.imread("Medical_Imaging/circuit.tif", as_grey=True)
```

You can see my image [here](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/data/tif/circuit.tif).

Answer (score 0):

skimage will only return images as float if they are already float, or if it needs to convert to float to do some calculations. For example, if the image data in the file is RGB, `as_gray=True` will need a weighted addition of all the channels (see [the `rgb2gray` function](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2gray)), so the image will be converted to float.

In your case, the image is already a grayscale uint8 image, so skimage does no conversion.

If you *do* want to make sure that your image is float, pass it through [`skimage.util.img_as_float`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.img_as_float).

Comment: Hi, some problems are solved, but still stuck with this ,,,,
rescale() got an unexpected keyword argument 'anti_aliasing'
any idea.. i think it is related to the version, any idea how to fix it? 
thanks.

Comment: You probably have an old version of scikit-image installed. Update it to a newer version that contains the anti_aliasing keyword.